# create a function that adds to a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

I have en assignment about lists that goes like this,

> Create a global variable called myUniqueList. It should be an empty list to start.
>
> Next, create a function that allows you to add things to that list. Anything that's passed to this function should get added to myUniqueList, unless its value already exists in myUniqueList. If the value doesn't exist already, it should be added and the function should return True. If the value does exist, it should not be added, and the function should return False;
>
> Finally, add some code below your function that tests it out. It should add a few different elements, showcasing the different scenarios, and then finally it should print the value of myUniqueList to show that it worked.
>
> Add another function that pushes all the rejected inputs into a separate global array called myLeftovers. If someone tries to add a value to myUniqueList but it's rejected (for non-uniqueness), it should get added to myLeftovers instead."

This is the code I have wrote to create the lists and add value to the list but I dont get the output I want from this code, can someone help me explain what I do wrong how do I write so my list get filled with elements? The Output I get from the code now, you can see below.

```
myUniqueList = []
myLeftovers = []

    def addList(newThing):
         if newThing in myUniqueList:
         myLeftovers.append(newThing)
         return False
         else:
         myUniqueList.append(newThing)
         return True

    print(myUniqueList) # []
    print(addList("Meliodas")) # returns 'True' since it's a new item
    print(addList("Escanor")) # returns 'True' since it's a new item
    print(addList("Meliodas")) # returns 'False' since it's already been added
    print(myUniqueList) # This includes the new entries
    print(myLeftovers) # This includes any repeated entries
```

I get

```
[]
False
False
False
[]
[]
```

Can you explain why the list dont get the words added and why I get Syntax Error on the else statement

Comment: please update the code indentation in your post so that we can understand what's going on

Comment: With proper indentation, the code works fine. https://ideone.com/JdfVJO

Comment: Side note: the assignment says: _Add another function that pushes all the rejected inputs into a separate global array called myLeftovers_ You haven't created that function.

Comment: Thanks all I got it at the end so now my code workes :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you were asked to create a global variable called myUniqueList. Since myUniqueList is a global list, in other to use it in a function, we have to tell the function we are using a global list by adding "global" before myUniqueList; hence your code will be as follows:

```
myUniqueList = []
myLeftovers = []

def add(newValue):
    global myUniqueList
    if newValue in myUniqueList:
        addToLeftovers(newValue)
        return False
    else:
          myUniqueList.append(newValue)
          return True

def addToLeftovers(newValue):
    myLeftovers.append(newValue)


# Testing the code:

print(add("Hello"))
print (myUniqueList)

print(add("Hello"))
print(myUniqueList)

print(myLeftovers)
```

Your Result will be as follows:

```
True
['Hello']
False
['Hello']
['Hello']
```

The first "Hello" came out TRUE while the second "Hello" came out FALSE. Then the third "Hello" was from the second hello which was rejected and now, pushed to the "myLeftovers" as stated in your question.